# Access PostgreSQL through a VPS

Tags: linux, postgresql, networking, ssh, proxy

I have the following situation:

- My VPS can access PostgreSQL on another machine
- My Linux laptop can't access the same PostgreSQL server for authentication reasons that shouldn't matter (I can't change anything about the setup)
- My laptop has full access to the VPS

Let's say the PostgreSQL host is `pg.some.domain`. Can I somehow use the VPS as a proxy so that I can connect to `pg.some.domain` from my laptop? I vaguely remember doing this using some easy-to-use CLI tool but now I can't find it after a lengthy Google session.

Comment: Never heard about a VPS, but maybe an SSL tunnel is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need port forwarding here.
Open an ssh connection from your laptop to the VPS and setup an ssh tunnel forwarding local port 5432 to pg.some.domain:5432 (I'm assuming postgres is running on standard port)

```
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:5432:pg.some.domain:5432 [your VPS IP here]
```

Now you should be able to access the PG server from your laptop by connecting to 127.0.0.1:5432

HTH

Comment: Good solution, though I ended up using the TCP proxy `balance` on the server.